# How do I update Homebrew?

Tags: git, homebrew

When I ran:

```
brew update
```

I got a message saying it initialized an empty repository in `/usr/local/.git/`, then I got this error:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If you are just looking for a quick way to fix this issue ASAP, you can do the following command in your shell while in the root of your Homebrew directory (usually /usr/local/) with Git installed on your system: `git init; git fetch https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git master; git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD; brew update`.

Answer (score 68):

- `cd /usr/local`
- `git status`
- Discard all the changes (unless you actually want to try to commit to Homebrew - you probably don't)
- `git status` til it's clean
- `brew update`

Comment: Instead of discarding changes, it may be better to `git stash` changes. Then after you're done updating, run `git stash pop` to restore your custom modifications

Comment: I did exactly this, stashed all changes in /usr/local ... but running 'brew update' continues to give me permission errors on certain git files. I made the mistake of doing 'sudo brew update' which now seems to have bricked my installation and every brew command now gives ruby errors

Comment: i did sudo brew update too and now getting that ruby errors like you said .. what do i do now? :'(

Comment: You can try to fix it by doing `sudo chown -R yourusername:admin /usr/local/.git`

Comment: FYI: it may also be `cd /usr/local/Homebrew`

Comment: Can't i just `git pull` to get the latest master? or pull a specific tag? why do i need to `brew update`?

Comment: NB currently sudo brew update yields;  Error: Cowardly refusing to 'sudo brew update'
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.

Comment: BE CAREFUL!! Discarding everything in your `/usr/local` directory could really mess up your computer. Make sure you know exactly what you're deleting before you use git to delete files in /usr/local (or anywhere else).

I'd recommend following the instructions here, instead: https://docs.brew.sh/Common-Issues

Answer (score 30):

As of 2021 you can simply use `brew update` which updates homebrew itself.

Comment: % brew update
Error: 
  homebrew-core is a shallow clone.
  homebrew-cask is a shallow clone.
To `brew update`, first run:
  git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow
  git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask fetch --unshallow
These commands may take a few minutes to run due to the large size of the repositories.
This restriction has been made on GitHub's request because updating shallow
clones is an extremely expensive operation due to the tree layout and traffic of
Homebrew/homebrew-core and Home.....

Comment: Not always. The default installation needs to be adapted before an upgrade command can work.

e.g. I needed to run these two commands


`git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core fetch --unshallow`


`git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask fetch --unshallow`


Before running `brew update`

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively you could update `brew` by installing it again. (Think I did this as El Capitan changed something)

**Note**: this is a heavy handed approach that will remove all applications installed via brew!

Try to install brew a fresh and it will tell how to uninstall.

At original time of writing to uninstall:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

**Edit:** As of 2020 to uninstall:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)"
```

Comment: be careful this script will remove all applications that you've installed via `brew`

Comment: Reinstalling brew with this method does not seem to cause installed applications to be removed anymore.