# Installing GDAL with Homebrew Error

Tags: homebrew, gdal

I'm currently working through [Let's make a map](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/#installing-tools) and I'm having difficulty installing GDAL. Here's the console output:

```
brew doctor
Your system is raring to brew.
Toms-MacBook-Pro:~ tomstove$ brew install gdal
==> Installing gdal dependency: sqlite
==> Downloading http://sqlite.org/2013/sqlite-autoconf-3071600.tar.gz
###################################                                       49.8%
curl: (33) HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume.
Error: Download failed: http://sqlite.org/2013/sqlite-autoconf-3071600.tar.gz
```

I'm on a mac running Mountain Lion so sqlite should already be installed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://sqlite.org/ doesn't support resume downloading.
Go to

`cd /Library/Caches/Homebrew`
or if you configurated other Location:
`brew --cache`

And delete all incomplete downloaded sqlite files (like `rm sqlite*`).

And then try 
`brew install sqlite`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide an answer. I'm not sure if it was a problem with resume downloading, but when I looked in `/Library/Caches` there was no `Homebrew` folder. Then I created one and it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was able to install by updating homebrew.

```
brew update
```

If you are have trouble running brew update, you probably need to fetch origin:
[brew update: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10762859/brew-update-the-following-untracked-working-tree-files-would-be-overwritten-by)

Comment: Hi, updated homebrew and reset git origin but still no luck. Thanks for your response though, I appreciate it