# Upgrading Maven on Mac

Tags: macos, maven-3

Tried to upgrade maven. Followed [this](http://myjeeva.com/how-to-do-maven-upgrade-in-mac-os-x.html) tutorial. Now I am getting this[image]

How does a file exist and not exist?

Comment: I did 1. brew update  2. brew search maven 3. brew install maven  4. mvn -version To double check 5. brew upgrade maven => it will throw an error 
Error: maven 3.5.4 already installed

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You created a symbolic link from your Downloads directory with a directory that may not exist anymore (or with an incorrect path). The directory /usr/bin/mvn obviously exists but the link is incorrect to the target which leads to the "No such file or directory" error when typing `mvm --version`.

Go through the tutorial again (which seems ok) but if you fail you could always try using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) with the following commands :

```
brew update
brew install maven
```

Comment: I went through the tutorial and did not work, brew worked. Thanks

Answer (score 53):

To upgrade to the latest version (if you have one already installed but need to update the version) do the following:

```
1. brew update
2. brew unlink maven
3. brew install maven
```

if you then execute the `mvn --version` command you should see that your version of maven has been upgraded.

**EDIT**:
If you have an issue with the update (command 1) that goes along the lines of 
`error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    Library/Formula/...` 
[try this answer from another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12031907/107301)

Comment: I also had to run `brew link --overwrite maven`

Comment: I just did `brew update && brew upgrade maven` and it worked :)

Answer (score 26):

if you installed maven in your mac, i use the next command...

```
>brew upgrade maven
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2dhJ.png)

Comment: Don't include screenshots on remote sites. Including images in answers is only marginally better. Its generally better to just include the text and use the SO to format it.

Answer (score 1):

I will be fixed if you run below commands

```
brew update
brew install maven
```

Still issue is exist check your M2_HOME path.
It should set to
`M2_HOME=/usr/local/bin/mvn`