# RVM: failure in installing latest version of ruby on Mac OSX El Capitan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I'm new to Ruby, and had the `2.0.0` version of Ruby on my mac by default. I was trying to get the latest version, and followed this question: [How to update Ruby to 1.9.x on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696564/how-to-update-ruby-to-1-9-x-on-mac), but even then, the latest version remains `2.0.0`. I copied some of the terminal commands I used:

```
Last login: Sun Oct 11 19:58:56 on console
Manish-MBP:~ manishgiri$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
Manish-MBP:~ manishgiri$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0    102      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   102
100 22721  100 22721    0     0   9052      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  9052
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.26.11.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.26.11/1.26.11.tar.gz.asc
Found PGP signature at: 'https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.26.11/1.26.11.tar.gz.asc',
but no GPG software exists to validate it, skipping.

Installing RVM to /Users/manishgiri/.rvm/
    Adding rvm PATH line to /Users/manishgiri/.profile /Users/manishgiri/.mkshrc /Users/manishgiri/.bashrc /Users/manishgiri/.zshrc.
    Adding rvm loading line to /Users/manishgiri/.profile /Users/manishgiri/.bash_profile /Users/manishgiri/.zlogin.
Installation of RVM in /Users/manishgiri/.rvm/ is almost complete:

  * To start using RVM you need to run `source /Users/manishgiri/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
    in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

# Manish-Giri,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io
rvm 1.26.11 (latest) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.11/x86_64/ruby-2.2.1.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system.......
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-2.2.1',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/manishgiri/.rvm/log/1444608144_ruby-2.2.1/update_system.log
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.'
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_error()  115 > rvm_pretty_print stderr
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  73 > case "${rvm_pretty_print_flag:=auto}" in
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  78 > case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  81 > case "$1" in
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  83 > [[ -t 2 ]]
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_pretty_print()  83 > return 1
++ /scripts/functions/logging : rvm_error()  117 > printf %b 'Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.\n'
Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions here:
    https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.
++ /scripts/functions/requirements/osx_brew : requirements_osx_brew_update_system()  381 > return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
Manish-MBP:~ manishgiri$ brew update
Error: The /usr/local directory is not writable.
Even if this directory was writable when you installed Homebrew, other
software may change permissions on this directory. Some versions of the
"InstantOn" component of Airfoil are known to do this.

You should probably change the ownership and permissions of /usr/local
back to your user account.
  sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
Manish-MBP:~ manishgiri$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):admin /usr/local
Password:
Manish-MBP:~ manishgiri$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
Manish-MBP:~ manishgiri$
```

It looked like there was an issue with homebrew, so I decided to update it. I did the **change ownership and permissions** part, and followed the instructions on this question - [How do I update Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024671/how-do-i-update-homebrew) and executed `brew update`. I got an `Already upto date` response.

Next, I tried `rvm list known` from the first answer, just to verify the latest version, and following that I executed `rvm install current && rvm use current`. I got this response:

```
Last login: Sun Oct 11 20:01:18 on ttys000
Manish-MBP:~ manishgiri$ rvm list known
# MRI Rubies
[ruby-]1.8.6[-p420]
[ruby-]1.8.7[-head] # security released on head
[ruby-]1.9.1[-p431]
[ruby-]1.9.2[-p330]
[ruby-]1.9.3[-p551]
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p643]
[ruby-]2.1.4
[ruby-]2.1[.5]
[ruby-]2.2[.1]
[ruby-]2.2-head
ruby-head

# for forks use: rvm install ruby-head-<name> --url https://github.com/github/ruby.git --branch 2.1

# JRuby
jruby-1.6.8
jruby[-1.7.19]
jruby-head
jruby-9.0.0.0.pre1

# Rubinius
rbx-1.4.3
rbx-2.4.1
rbx[-2.5.2]
rbx-head

# Opal
opal

# Minimalistic ruby implementation - ISO 30170:2012
mruby[-head]

# Ruby Enterprise Edition
ree-1.8.6
ree[-1.8.7][-2012.02]

# GoRuby
goruby

# Topaz
topaz

# MagLev
maglev[-head]
maglev-1.0.0

# Mac OS X Snow Leopard Or Newer
macruby-0.10
macruby-0.11
macruby[-0.12]
macruby-nightly
macruby-head

# IronRuby
ironruby[-1.1.3]
ironruby-head
Manish-MBP:~ manishgiri$ rvm install current && rvm use current
system
Now using system ruby.
```

After all of that, I thought it would have upgraded to `2.2.3` but when I ran `ruby -v`, I still got: `ruby 2.0.0p645 (2015-04-13 revision 50299) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]`.

Why did the update fail? I have installed RubyInstaller on my windows PC and that uses `2.2.3`.

Comment: so what happens when you do rvm install 2.2.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating Homebrew, exit Terminal, and re-open. Then rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p551 <- Use your version #

Also make sure to set it as default. rvm --default use {version #}, exit Terminal, and re-open.

I got it by accident. Some of it from this YouTube video: [Setting Up Ruby [ Ruby on Rails from the Ground Up - 2/5 ]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxTR7rWaQw8). The rest was by poking it with a sharp stick.